# Pegar quantidade especifica de caracteres de um textbox

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou tentando pegar uma quantidade específica de caracteres digitados em um texbox, o código atual é o seguinte:

```
novaconfiguracao.CupomEstabelecimento = tb_NomeFantasia.Text.Substring(0,48).ToString();
```

No caso independente de ser digitado menos de 48 ou mais de 48 pegar no máximo até 48.

Comment: E qual é a dúvida? Você já está fazendo o que diz querer.

Comment: O problema é que ta dando erro

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues complete a pergunta com todos os detalhes relevantes, por favor. Sugestão de leitura: **[Ask]**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa pegar o menor valor dos dois. Ou o 48 ou tamanho da *string*. Se tentar pegar 48 caracteres e a *string* for menor que isto dará um erro de índice.

Será assim:

```
novaconfiguracao.CupomEstabelecimento = 
              tb_NomeFantasia.Text.Substring(0, Math.Min(tb_NomeFantasia.Text.Length, 48));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CAk18Q). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bEG5e3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/GetSubstring.cs).

Não entendi esse `ToString()` que você tinha colocado.